# using knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

i have database value "active" returning true and false value from sql query . i want the checkbox should be ticked when `active =true` and unchecked when `active=false`. i have used mvc model in php

what should i do? its a php page.

```
  <div class="datagrid">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="additionaltable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="span1">
                    Questions
                </th>
                <th class="span1">
                    Active
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
            <tr data-id="value:id">
                <td data-bind="text:question">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and i have 1 more query ... the table loads up with data .. on clicking in data in table , the values should be displayed in textbox ..what to do for this?

Comment: and i have 1 more query ... the table loads up with data .. on clicking  in data in table , the values should be displayed in textbox ..what to do for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "displayed in textbox"? Is that a separate textbox?

Comment: there is serperate textbox . i was talking about
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active" />
                </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lines -

```
<td data-bind="text:question">
</td>
```

Won't work. You have to text bind to a span to get the behavior you want.

```
<td> 
   <span data-bind="text:question"></span>
</td>
```

I put together a working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/kBKzv/4/

Comment: Binding to the `td` using the text binding works as well. The question however, is a bit unclear.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg, thanks for clarifying for me.  However, when I tried the binding as in the question, it didn't work.

Comment: when i use ` <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active" />` the checkbox is ticked all of them

Comment: here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/easS6/  and there is sql query which brings json data

Comment: tom is saw your fiddle in ur fiddle , checkbox works correctly then why not in my code ??